# range of sum of linear operators

Tags: functional-analysis

Is the following statement true?

Consider two linear operators $A,B: X \to X$ s.t. $A\neq -B$. 
If $\overline{ran(A)}=\overline{ran(B)}=X$ then $\overline{ran(A+B)}=X$.

I'm having trouble proving this statement, so if someone could give me a hint (or a counter example) that would be great! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, take $B = -A$.

[30 characters minimum]

Comment: Agreed. And if $B \neq -A$?

Comment: $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, $B =  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$ is another example.

Comment: That's true, thanks.

Comment: What I was trying to prove with this approach is that the residual spectrum of a linear operator on a Hilbert space X is invariant under compact perturbations, i.e. let $A=A_0 + K$ where $K$ is a compact operator, so $\overline{ran(K)}=X$. Then $\sigma_r(A) \equiv \sigma_r(A_0)$.